# Assigning a structure to a structure array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to assign a structure to an empty structure array. For example-

```
a=struct([]);
a(1)=b;
```

where `b` is a structure itself containing multiple fields, ex:

```
b=struct('ID',1,'pass',34);
```

But this doesn't work. I can do the following-

```
a(1).field=b;
```

but this makes other portions of the code cumbersome.

actually in my code, `b` is coming from a separate function which will be called several times. I just need to add the returned structures to a structure array. Or any other suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `a` to be a proper structure array, i.e. initialise it with the compatible set of fields:

```
a = struct('ID', {}, 'pass', {});
b = struct('ID', 1, 'pass', 34);
a(1) = b;
```